# Adding splitted values in loops

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

I suggest u look at this picture, and then u look at the code I have written:

```
function addNumbers() {
    var splitted = document.getElementById("listInput").value.split(" ");

    for(i = 0; i <= splitted.length; i+=1) {
        document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal").value = splitted[i];
    }
}
```

I am taking the value from the box which says "Enter list of numbers and/or words" and I am splitting it. I split it so I have all the numbers like this "1 2 3" and so I can add them. I use the for loop for that. The for loop goes through every number and then it adds it. But when I press the button, it shows me undefined.

Why am I getting undefined?

Comment: Show us the html where you defined all the elements with ids. Also tell us **which** variable is undefined.

Comment: Why not just `for(i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {`...if you are a `performance guy`, you can use an extra variable to store the length, in order to not calculate that value again for every step in the loop

Comment: it's because `i<= splitted.length`, your code goes out of array (beacuse that `=`, since array start from 0 (zero), not 1)... correct will be `i<splitted.length; x++` and, of course, will show only last result from array... eg. if you enter in `listInput` `1 2 3` it will display only `3`

Comment: So how do I add the numbers inside that box. I want the loop to go through every number and add it. How do I do that? And you are write Im only getting 3 as a result, not the addition of the 3 numbers inside the box

Comment: @DONTRU See my answer as to how to add the numbers up using `.reduce()`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting undefined, because you are displaying the value of the last element of the array and not doing the `Sum` as you mentioned in the question.

Following code always overrides the value of `resultNumberTotal` by the value of `splitted[i]`. Since, your `for` loop iterates for `i <= splitted.length` it reaches the index which doesn't exist in the array, when you get a property which doesn't exist on an object, you get `undefined`

```
 for(i = 0; i < splitted.length; i+=1) {
        document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal").value = splitted[i];
    }
```

So, for doing the sum, you need to make the code like

```
function addNumbers() {
    var splitted = document.getElementById("listInput").value.split(" ");
    var total = 0;    
    for(i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
       var numberValue = +splitted[i];
       if(!isNaN(numberValue)){
        total = total + numberValue ;
       }

    }
   document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal").value = total;
}
```

Comment: I think in the second code snippet you meant to move the updating of .value outside of the loop, and assign `total` to it

Comment: Should be `.value = total`

Comment: I am getting a NaN error now but I think I may be able to find a way from here. Your code makes sense thank you

Comment: You can make use of isNaN function, which returns if the argument passed is number or NaN otherwise.

Comment: Using `parseInt` to determine if a string is a number is bad practice. parseInt is for **parsing** numbers off the front of a string until it sees a non-number. `Number(...)` is for converting a string to a number. For example.. `parseInt("21GunSalute")` returns `21`, whereas Number() would return `NaN`. Also, base 10 is implied by default with parseInt since ES5 -- no need to explicitly pass in the base. This will also go out of bounds of the array with `i <= splitted.length` because the length of the array is always 1 more than the last index. Won't throw an error, but it's unnecessary.

Comment: I didn't knew about the parseInt leading number behavior, updated the code to  convert the string to number using the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow add the numbers up, either using the `+=` operator, or by using something like [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as I have done below.

```js
function addNumbers() {
  var val = document.getElementById("listInput").value;
  document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal").value = val.split(" ").reduce(function(runningTotal, currentArrayElement) {
    // make sure the value they typed is a number
    // if not, fail gracefully and simply ignore it
    if (!isNaN(Number(currentArrayElement))) {
      // if it is a number, add it to the running total
      runningTotal+= Number(currentArrayElement);
    }
    return runningTotal; // return the running total
  }, 0); // start with 0 as the initial value for runningTotal
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="listInput" placeholder="insert values here..." style="width: 300px;" />
<button onclick="addNumbers()">Add Numbers</button>

<br/>
<br/>
<hr/>

Number Total: <input id="resultNumberTotal"/>
```

Comment: Thank you your code actually worked, but I don't get what ".reduce" is and and what curr is. Can you explain that plz?

Comment: @DONTRU reduce is an array iteration function that is designed to "reduce" a collection of items (array) down to a single value, whether it be a string, number, object, etc. In this case we want an array of values to reduce to a single number, so reduce is perfect for the job. The arguments in the reduce callback are (in order) the running total, or the single value that you are reducing to (again, whether it be an object, string, number, etc.) and the second parameter is the current item in the array that it is looking at.

Comment: @DONTRU I have updated my post to make it explicitly clear what the code is doing. Also, see the docs for `.reduce()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

```
function addNumbers() {
var splitted = document.getElementById("listInput").value.split(" ");
 //make sure that the values are in a number format
 document.getElementById("resultNumberTotal").value = splitted.reduce(function(a, b) {return Number(a) + Number(b);}, 0)
}
```

for the best practice make sure that allow number only for the input fields :) good luck